Why does typescript infer a generic type differently if a property is included that uses it?
I'm trying to create an function that accepts a props object, where the return type of one property is used as the constraint for the args of another.
Consider the following code:

// A base type and another type that extends from it

interface Base { x: string; }
interface Foo extends Base { y: number; }

// A fn type that accepts Foos as an argument

type Fn<T> = (t: T) => void
declare const FooFn: Fn<Foo>

// Now, I want to use the return type of 'x' to constrain the type of fn I can assign to 'y' contravariantly

type Baz = <R extends Base, F extends Fn<R>>(arg: {
  x: (bar: Foo) => R
  y?: F[]
}) => R;

// Observe that if I try to set 'y', FooFn emits an error
// Even though R is inferred from 'x' correctly (see R1)

declare const baz: Baz;
const R1 = baz({ x: (ctx) => ctx })
const R2 = baz({ x: (ctx) => ctx, y: [FooFn] }) 


The return type of 'x' is inferred differently based on whether 'y' is declared.
Using NoInfer in F doesn't help either.
Why would the return type be Context when 'y' is declared, but MyContext when 'y' is omitted?
To be clear, my goal is to be able to set 'y' to an array of fns that can accept the return type of 'x'.
I also put this in a TS playground:
https://tsplay.dev/mxpM7m

I guess not! Sorry, I already ripped out a bunch of code and didn't think to squeeze out those last few lines...

• I would squeeze it all the way down to this version; nobody here can say much about your underlying use case, and you seem to be asking about how inference works. This is essentially identical to your question but without extra stuff. Would you consider [edit]ing it to that version? • If so, I suspect this is one of the pathological cases of ms/TS#47599. I know why in general these things affect inference, but not specifically why there's a failure here.

I just realised you must get notifications whenever anyone uses your link shortener :D Clever...
I was scratching my head over your reduced version, until I noticed you're passing baz into the array, rather than BarFn.
I made some changes and I'll update my question to reflect your minimal repro.

I... don't get notifications that way. I'm not in control of tsplay.dev.  I just watch Stack Overflow too much.  Yeah, check the most recent link, I think I fixed that.

Oh really? I thought you built it, for some reason... Anyway question updated!

This is ms/TS#47599. TS has a heuristic inference algorithm. When generic types and callback param types from context need inference at once, the algorithm can fail. It tends to defer inference of a context-sensitive fn like ctx => ctx; which is bad if another step needs that result earlier. In the 1st call F cannot be inferred, so it's basically just inferring R. In the 2nd call F needs R first for the constraint, but R has been deferred and . Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an a; if not, what am I missing?

Yes thanks... so TL/DR TS isn't quite smart enough...
I added my example to the GH Issue, thanks for the link up!

This is a known limitation or missing feature of TypeScript's inference algorithm, as described in microsoft/TypeScript#47599. When calling a generic function without manually specifying the type arguments, TypeScript tries to infer them. And when writing a callback function without manually annotating their parameters, TypeScript tries to infer them from context. When your generic function call also includes unannotated callbacks, so that TypeScript has to infer both at once, then if these types depend on each other in any way, it's quite possible for inference to fail. It might be obvious to a human being how to analyze the code so that at each step you only need information you already have, but TypeScript's heuristic algorithm happens in a particular order, and if it ends up needing something now that it won't be able to infer until later, you'll run into issues.
If you read microsoft/TypeScript#47599, you'll see that whether or not the inference succeeds depends on things you might not think should have any effect. So the answer to the question in the title is: simultaneous inference of type arguments and callback parameters is fragile, and sensitive in ways you might not expect.

In your case, it looks like for the
const R1 = baz({ x: (ctx) => ctx })

call, there is absolutely nowhere TypeScript can infer F at all, so it doesn't even try. Instead, it focuses solely on R. It needs to know ctx's type before it can know R, so when it gets to the phase of inference where it infers contextual parameter types, ctx gets the type Foo, and then R is inferred as Foo, as desired.  F just falls back to its constraint, which is Fn<R>, and therefore Fn<Foo>.
But with
const R2 = baz({ x: (ctx) => ctx, y: [FooFn] }) 

now TypeScript makes an attempt to infer F from the type of FooFn. It needs to do this in the absence of an inference for R, because R can only be inferred from the return type of x (no, the constraint F extends Fn<R> does not help the compiler infer R, see microsoft/TypeScript#7234). But at this stage, TypeScript has no idea what ctx is because it hasn't tried contextual typing yet. So all TypeScript knows about R is that it is constrained to Base. And so TypeScript assumes that R is just Base, in order to constrain F. And then things explode because FooFn is not assignable to Fn<Base>. Everything falls back to its constraint and inference fails.
That's the answer to the question in the body of the post.

The general issue will almost certainly always be present in TypeScript, but there have been occasional improvements, such as the added support in TypeScript 4.7 as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#48538. Maybe someday your code above will just start working as-is. In the meantime you need to work around it.
If you want R to be inferrable from FooFn, then you can use the suggestion in microsoft/TypeScript#7234 to use intersections instead of constraints. Maybe like this:
type Baz = <R extends Base, F extends Fn<R>>(arg: {
  x: (bar: Foo) => R
  y?: (Fn<R> & F)[]
}) => R;

const R2 = baz({ x: (ctx) => ctx, y: [FooFn] }) // okay

This is essentially the same thing, more or less (although intersections of functions are weird), and inference will now succeed because y contains enough information from which to infer R... as long as the elments of y already have known function parameter types. If, instead of FooFn, you put another xxx => xxx, all bets are off.
If all else fails, just annotate your function parameters:
const R2 = baz({ x: (ctx: Foo) => ctx, y: [FooFn] });

Yes, the compiler "should" do that for you. It doesn't; you need to help it out.
Playground link to code
